# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'futval.py'; 'futval' is not a package

Tags: python

I am a beginner with Python and using Python 3.6.0 on Mac OS X 10.12. I imported a module saved in my documents folder with all of my other modules that worked fine, yet it came back with this after the module ran:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import futval.py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'futval.py'; 'futval' is not a package
```

All of my other modules ran fine before this one and I can't figure out the issue. I've searched around the site for answers and can't seem to find anything. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

If you're trying to import a file named `futval.py`, you need to write just `import futval`; the name of the module does not include the `.py`.

Comment: Awesome jwodder.  You solved an error of mine I've been trying to figure out.  Thanks for taking the time to write this <: